# Standardjs ignores .eslintrc file

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, eslint, standardjs

I use Standardjs by an extension in VSCode (the linter is installed globally, basically everything I open in Code is linted by Standard.js until I decide not to). I wanted to ignore a rule, so I went by advice from the internet and created `.eslint.json` file in the project folder with following content:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "quotes": "off"
  }
}
```

But it doesn't work. At all. I also tried to run Standard.js from command line with the same result, so the problem might not be with the extension.

I'm pretty sure I don't have some broken configuration as disabling the rule by a comment works.

`/* eslint quotes: off */`

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

StandardJS don't allow you to disable rules like that, as their intention [is avoiding "bikeshedding" about code style](https://standardjs.com/#i-disagree-with-rule-x-can-you-change-it)